# Is MySQL commit synchronous when executed from PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, commit

Using the PHP PDO interface to MySQL, suppose I have this code to end a transaction (assuming it was properly begun):

```
$pdo->query('commit');
```

When the function returns, have writes to the log been flushed? That is, is the transaction committed, or have I merely made a request that it be committed? Assuming that I have not set any options to delay flushing, such as, for example, setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to zero.

I ask because, if I were to follow the code above with this:

```
echo 'Transaction has been committed.';
```

I wouldn't want to be caught in a lie.

UPDATE: See the comments below. I'm not asking how InnoDB works. I'm asking whether the PDO interface waits for the InnoDB engine to execute the command before returning.

UPDATE #2: I should have said that the commit would be performed by a call to PDO::commit, which is how I actually do it, in case there's any difference between that and doing it with SQL.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would the user know you're lying? They'd need direct access to the DB and to query the database after you printed the message, but before the commit had been actually committed (assuming there is a delay, which I doubt there is).

Comment: it'd be pretty much like issuing `commit` in the mysql monitor command line. if you get a prompt back, the commit's been completed. however, that doesn't mean there might not still be disk activity going on in the background.

Comment: How would the user know I were lying? The user might see the message and then discover some time later that, because of a power failure, the transaction was lost. I would hate to have to change the wording of the message to "Transaction might be committed; keep your fingers crossed."

Comment: Here's more about the way InnoDB works, from the manual: "If the value of innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit is 0, the log buffer is written out to the log file once per second and the flush to disk operation is performed on the log file, but nothing is done at a transaction commit. When the value is 1 (the default), the log buffer is written out to the log file at each transaction commit and the flush to disk operation is performed on the log file. When the value is 2, ..."

Comment: Marc B: I don't think you've described the default behavior. See my quote from the manual above. But, you get a +10 for knowing how to spell your first name. ;-)

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing.  I have an MQ pipeline, and if I don't put in a delay, the MQ receiver pulls the old data from MySQL.