# Are PHP PDO commit()s synchronous?

Tags: php, pdo, synchronization

My question is a carbon copy of this question from 2013 which never got an answer:

[Is MySQL commit synchronous when executed from PHP PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466753/is-mysql-commit-synchronous-when-executed-from-php-pdo)

In summary, once I have a return value from a PDO commit() can I be certain that my transaction has been committed and any database locks released?

Comment: Well, the PDO::commit docs say `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.` I don't know how you would try to disprove this. It might be a question of how the database answers PHP.

Comment: We're finding that occasionally accessing a database from one process after changing it in another results in mismatched data. What isn't clear is whether this is caused by database locks outside of PDO's control, or if the transaction is only scheduled at the point commit returns.